# Visual Basic Dynamic Type Conversion and Comparison

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I'm attempting to create a function to test the equality of two members of a DataRow object, all of which are initially strings, but need to be converted to their actual data types before comparison. If the data can't be converted to the actual data type, the function should return false. This is the general framework that I'm shooting for.

```
Private Function compareValues(ByVal row as DataRow, ByVal field as String, ByVal dType as Type) as Boolean
    ' Get the raw values from the DataRow
    Dim raw1 As String = row("t1_" + field).ToString() 
    Dim raw2 As String = row("t2_" + field).ToString() 
    Dim val1, val2 As dtype

    ' Try to convert the raw strings to the target type
    Try
        val1 = CType(raw1, dType) '<--Error here
        val2 = CType(raw2, dType) '<--Error here
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False ' If either conversion fails, return false
    End Try

    ' Compare the values in their actual types and return false is they don't match
    If (Not val1 = val2) Then
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

The error I get is: `Type 'dType' is not defined.`

I've attempted to genericize the function by using the `Of` clause:

```
Private Function compareValues(Of dtype)(ByVal row As DataRow, ByVal field As String) As Boolean
    Dim raw1 As String = row("t1_" + field).ToString()
    Dim raw2 As String = row("t2_" + field).ToString()
    Dim val1, val2 As dtype
    Try
        val1 = CTypeDynamic(Of dtype)(raw1)
        val2 = CTypeDynamic(Of dtype)(raw2)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    If (Not val1 = val2) Then '<--Error here
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Trying this, however, results in the error: `Operator '=' is not defined for types 'dtype' and 'dtype'.` Generally speaking, I don't think I'm using the of clause correctly.

Given a datarow, `dr`, with two fields, `t1_size` and `t2_size`, having respective values of "01.92" and "1.92", I'm aiming to call the function like this:

```
Dim match as Boolean = compareValues(dr, "size", Double) 'evaluates to True
```

Given the same datarow and fields having respective values of "01.90" and "1.92", the function should be called in the same manner, but return False.

Considering respective values of `t1_size` and `t2_size` as "apple" and "01.92", the function should be called in the same manner as the previous examples and still return False.

### Resolution/Implementation:

Steven Doggart and Styxxy brought it home with each of their contributions. Please find below the working code:

```
Private Function compareValues(Of dtype)(row As DataRow, field As String) As Boolean
    Dim val1 As dtype
    Dim val2 As dtype
    Try
        val1 = CType(row("t1_" + field), dtype)
        val2 = CType(row("t2_" + field), dtype)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    If (Not val1.Equals(val2)) Then
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

Called as follows, assuming you have a DataRow with two columns you wish to compare for equality, "t1_size" and "t2_size", each holding the string representation of a floating point number:

```
Dim match as Boolean = compareValues(Of Double)(dr, "size")
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use the [`Field` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field.aspx) on the datarow.

Comment: There are various problems with your approach. In any case, you don't need to do all that as far as you are willing to pass the given datarow (whose type is known). I understand from your examples that what you want is a function determining whether the two records of the given datarow are equal or not, independently upon the types (if the types are different, the function would return False). If this is what you want, you don't have to analyse the datarow type but its values. You can use Field (which can account for different types), as suggested by Styxxy, or just check types via TypeOf.

Comment: Thanks for the answers @Styxxy and @steven! I've tried the condensed version provided by Steven Doggart, and while I understand the aim, I'm still getting the same error as before: Operator '=' not defined for types 'dtype' and 'dtype'. 

Just for (probably unnecessary) clarification, I have not created a type named dtype, this is just the variable name I'm passing into the function.

Comment: Use the Equals method. That should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it backwards.  When `dtype` is a `Type` variable, you should use the `CTypeDynamic` method, for instance:

```
Private Function compareValues(row as DataRow, field as String, dType as Type) as Boolean
    ' ...
    val1 = CTypeDynamic(raw1, dtype)
    ' ...
End Function
```

And when `dtype` is a generic type, you should use `CType`, for instance:

```
Private Function compareValues(Of dtype)(row As DataRow, field As String) As Boolean
    ' ...
    val1 = CType(raw1, dtype)
    ' ...
End Function
```

However, you probably want to define `raw1` and `raw2` as `Object` and set them to the actual field value.  I doubt that you really want to convert them to strings just to turn around and convert them back into their proper data type again.  For instance:

```
Dim raw1 As Object = row("t1_" + field)
Dim raw2 As Object = row("t2_" + field)
```

As Styxxy pointed out, the generic `Field` extension method was added in version 3.5 of the .NET Framework.  It does the conversion for you, so you could skip the "raw" part and do something like this:

```
Private Function compareValues(Of dtype)(row As DataRow, field As String) As Boolean
    Dim val1 As dtype = row.Field(Of dtype)("t1_" + field)
    ' ...
End Function
```